# ArangoDB: 'Could not connect to 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8529' 'connect() failed with #10061

Tags: connection, d, libcurl, arangodb

Sometimes my ArangoDB is going down with next error:
`Error message 'Could not connect to 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8529' 'connect() failed with #10061`
I can't understand the reason. It's look like I am turning on my PC and nothing do not work.
Before I fixed this problem with reinstall, but is there any better solution?

OS Windows
ArangoDB 2.8.7

Comment: Are you using connection keepalive in your client?

Comment: it's go down when I do not used it. I am using curl and https://github.com/ikod/dlang-requests with default options.

Comment: seems to me like you need to handle connection close events in your libcurl handler code to re-establish the connection?

Comment: @dothebart the DB is go offline when I do not use it. Same situation on my home PC and at work. I can't even to understand how to get it up

Comment: Do you find any output in the windows event log?

Comment: @dothebart I do not see nothing there :(

Answer (score 3):

The V8 version used in the pre ArangoDB 3 had occasional troubles in the garbage collection which would make ArangoDB in term go down.

This is fixed with ArangoDB 3.

Please upgrade your installation, and report back whether the problem still persists.

You can use [netstat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) to check whether ArangoDB is listening to its default port `8529`:

```
netstat -a 
Active Connections
Proto  Lokale Adresse         Remoteadresse          Status
...
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8529         meschenich:0           LISTEN
...
```

If thats not the case, your client has nothing to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to firewall of an antivirus.
In my case it was Avast antivirus that was blocking connecting to that port.

I disabled all the antivirus shields and checked loading arangodb web server 
http://127.0.0.1:8529
It connects after few minutes.

Reference : [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/58e420e9-43a3-4119-b541-d18158038e36/tcp-error-code-10061-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it?forum=wcf)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by restarting Windows.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error appeared to me when I entered any wrong password.

The scenario is like the following:

1. I installed ArangoDB for the first time. And tried, to login using `arangosh` command.
2. It asks me for a password `"Please specify a password:"`.
3. I entered any wrong password, and as a result of that, the login is failed, and showing the above error.

The default login credentials for a fresh arangodb installation are:

**user**: root

**password**: (Blank) - *Don't type anything*